# IntelliJ IDEA - no Export IDE settings menu item

Tags: intellij-idea

Today I upgraded my Intellij IDEA to 2018.3, but I can not find the Settings Export feature. [image: File menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not available when you have [Settings Sync](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html) enabled via JetBrains Account.

There is an open issue:

- [IDEA-202548](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202548) No export/import settings when IDE settings sync is enabled

Disabling settings sync will bring the menu back.

Comment: In reality i have resolved my problem by disable plugin "Settings Repository".

Comment: Yes, disabling the plug-in will have the same effect.